# R X12 automdl trouble

Tags: r, x12

Does anyone have an idea why I might receive this error:

Error in automdl && is.null(arima) : invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'

When attempting to run the second example in the R package x12?

```
library(x12)
data(AirPassengers)
x12out <- x12(AirPassengers,x12path="c:\\x12arima\\x12a.exe",transform="auto",
          automdl="TRUE")
```

Running the first example with the fulling specified ARIMA works.

```
x12out <- x12(AirPassengers,x12path="c:\\x12arima\\x12a.exe",transform="auto",
          arima=c(0,1,1),sarima=c(0,1,1),regvariables="lpyear",
          sigmalim=c(2.0,3.0),outlier="all",critical=list(LS=3.5,TC=3),
          seasonalma="s3x3")
```

Clearly the "automdl" is choking for some reason?

Comment: Try `automdl = TRUE`, without the quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message

```
Error in automdl && is.null(arima) : invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'
```

is helpful. It shows that when R tried to run `x && y`, it found that `x` had an invalid type. It also tells us that `x` here is `automdl`. `&&` being a logical operator, `automdl` should be a logical: `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

You made a mistake when setting `automdl` to `"TRUE"` (a character); it should be `TRUE` (a logical).

(I would also agree the function's documentation is confusing.)

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. Its always the little things that trip me up. TRUE no quotes worked.